# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I have a problem accessing my sharepoint site using the server ip address, but using http://localhost:port/ or  http://servername:port/ works fine. Also ordinary IIS sites work fine when accessing using IP address, its only sharepoint sites that display error: "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid"

I have read a lot about making the changes in the host file, IIS bindings and also Alternate Access Mapping, I have done all that in vain. There is no solution even while googling this error. I hope someone kind will help me answer this.

Comment: question is, are you accessing within the server or externally like on you laptop? localhost tells me within the server

Comment: First when I try within the server and gives the error, when I test externally using the IP address of the server I still get the same error, but server name works fine, the problem is I can not use the IP address of the server as it results into that error

Comment: Is there going to be an answer to this question ever?

Comment: just add the ip to the aam (alternate access mapping) under internet. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings

Comment: I did all that without any sucess, I actually have a public IP already mapped, other sites work well with the public IP as well, but only Sharepoint sites give that error.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

Go to Central Administration > Manage services on server  > Request Management

Stop service and it will work fine.

**Reference link:**

[can't access Sharepoint 2013 site via IP Address](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/386cf09b-c2d6-487c-8721-c5596ca50dd2/cant-access-sharepoint-2013-site-via-ip-address)

Comment: you are super super Thx a lot its working :D !!!!